# Can anyone help me with this simple For Loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
/* Write a program that asks the user
 * to enter the starting point and end
 * point of the counting range and the 
 * increment value and displays the total 
 * of the numbers within that range
 */

int start;
int end;
int increment;
int sum = 0;
int count= 0;

Console.WriteLine(" Enter the start number ");
start = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(" Enter the end number ");
end = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(" Enter the increment number ");
increment = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for ( start = ; end <= start ; count = count + increment  )
{

    Console.WriteLine(" Number is: " + count);

}

Console.WriteLine(" Sum is: " + sum);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Your for-loop is incorrect

Comment: There is no question here, just a homework assignment and some code. Be clear about what you're stuck with, what are the expected vs actual results, error messages etc.

Comment: Im preparing for a test in a couple of days on loops and this is a sample question

this is what i am getting back

Enter the start number 1 Enter the end number 10 Enter the increment number 2 Number is: 0 Sum is: 0 this is what the console window is prompting back to me??

Comment: You never calculate a sum!

Comment: i am completely new to this i am just going by my lecture notes, where there is no solution given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify your code a bit

```
/* Write a program that asks the user
 * to enter the starting point and end
 * point of the counting range and the 
 * increment value and displays the total 
 * of the numbers within that range
 */

int start;
int end;
int increment;
int sum = 0;
int count= 0;

Console.WriteLine(" Enter the start number ");
start = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(" Enter the end number ");
end = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(" Enter the increment number ");
increment = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for ( count = start; //init value for count
      count <= end ; //check every loop. if count still satify condition, then do thing inside tho loop
      count += increment //change count every a loop done
    )
{
    sum += count; 
    Console.WriteLine(" Number is: " + count);

}

Console.WriteLine(" Sum is: " + sum);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: this seems to be working ! thank you !

also, can you explain the for statement ? 
1. initialization  count = start ?
2. guard ... while the count is less than end ?
3. make progress ... count = count + increment

Comment: I try to explain above code, but I think it's better to look into detail tut https://www.dotnetperls.com/for

Answer (score 0):

You want a loop while `start` < `end`, and every time that condition is met, the counter is incremented by `increment`.

This would be the structure of your loop:

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i += increment) 
{
    // Add to total and display current value
}
```

Comment: Enter the start number
1
 Enter the end number
10
 Enter the increment number
2
 Number is: 0
 Sum is: 0


this is what the console window is prompting back to me??

Comment: Don't declare `count` before the loop. The loop should be `for (int count = start; count < end; count += increment)`. Then of course the sum gets not calculated automatically. Since it is never changed it remains 0.